# How to change constructor arguments?

Tags: equalsverifier

I have a record that performs a verification in its constructor as such :

```java
public record Configuration(URI url) {
  public Configuration(URI url) {
    Validate.httpValid(url, "url");
  }
}
```

Where the `httpValid` method is :

```java
public static URI httpValid(final URI value, final String property) {
    try {
      value.toURL();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new InvalidPropertyValueException(property, "httpValid", value, Map.of());
    }
    return value;
  }
```

This however fails the test i'm trying to create :

```java
@Test
  void Should_RespectEqualsContract() {
    EqualsVerifier
        .forClass(Configuration.class)
        .withPrefabValues(
            Configuration.class,
            new Configuration(URI.create("http://a.com")),
            new Configuration(URI.create("http://b.com")))
        .verify();
  }
```

This is because EqualsVerifier is trying to create an object with "x" as argument :
`InvalidPropertyValueException: The value x is not a valid httpValid as url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You shouldn't provide the class that you're testing as a prefab value; instead you need to provide the paramter that's causing trouble, like this:

```java
@Test
void Should_RespectEqualsContract() {
    EqualsVerifier
        .forClass(Configuration.class)
        .withPrefabValues(
            URI.class,
            URI.create("http://a.com"),
            URI.create("http://b.com"))
        .verify();
}
```